# Is there anyway to include an external rules file other than hosts in dnsmasq.conf?

Tags: dnsmasq

In my `dnsmasq.conf`, I include thousands of rules, e.g. `address=/example.net/`

I know that it is possible to include an external *hosts* file using the line `addn-hosts=/etc/hosts`

But is there a way to include a file containing rules in the form of `address=/example.net/`?

Comment: Not what you specifically asked for but maybe [`--conf-script`](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) can facilitate the actual goal?

Comment: Thanks. It is rather `--conf-file`. I tried it and so far it works..

Comment: Alright, I was (incorrectly?) assuming that you were already using `--conf-file` but wanted something that it did not provide. (Maybe multiple `--conf-file` specifically is the trick?)

Comment: Exactly. That's it, thanks. If you write it as an answer I'll accept it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`--conf-file`](https://thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) option can be used multiple times to read additional configuration files, which sounds like a way of solving your problem.

> **-C, --conf-file=<file>**
> Specify a configuration file. The presence of this option stops dnsmasq from reading the default configuration file
> (normally /etc/dnsmasq.conf). Multiple files may be specified by
> repeating the option either on the command line or in configuration
> files. A filename of "-" causes dnsmasq to read configuration from
> stdin.